# Python Qt Designer Button that creates subsequent text entries

Tags: windows, qt, python-2.7, widget

I'm trying to make a GUI in Qt Designer that has one text entry box and a button off to the side that inserts another text entry box below the first. I would potentially need to do this a dozen times or more.

This is my example code from Qt Designer:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(247, 300)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 10, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit1 = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 31, 20))
        self.lineEdit1.setObjectName("lineEdit1")
        self.lineEdit2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 10, 31, 20))
        self.lineEdit2.setObjectName("lineEdit2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        # QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), Dialog.add_wells) #
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "PushButton", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

and this is the code to run the GUI:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
import sys

import addentryexample


class MainWindow(QDialog, addentryexample.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.connect(self.pushButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.add_entry)

    def add_entry(self):

        pass



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

I'm struggling on how to iterate each name of the text box entry so I can pick the values from them later on. I think placing them should just require adding a certain amount to each 'setGeometry' attribute.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findChildren`:

```
lineEdits = form.findChildren(QLineEdit)
for lineEdit in lineEdits:
    print lineEdit.objectName()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but could you explain it a bit more? Based on what I know, this would help me find all of the values in the line edits after I made a few new ones. This should work well for that, but what about creating new line edits that have different names with a button click?

Comment: Should be no problem, just use `setObjectName()` on every manually created widget. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I need to become much more familiar with those included functions...

Comment: Is there a way to do this without making QtGui a global variable?

Comment: When you do `import *` you don't have to prepend `QtGui.`.

Comment: One last question: I have everything working except I need to update the GUI every time a new line edit is made. How can I do that without threading?